# returning tmp using references behaving differently

Tags: c++, reference

I know that returning temporary variables using references doesn't work since the temporary object is lost after the function terminates, but the following piece of code works since the returned temporary is assigned to another object.

I assume the temporary objects get destroyed after the line of function call. If it is so, why isn't this working for this kind of method chaining?

```
Counter& Counter::doubler()
{ 
   Counter tmp;
   tmp.i = this->i * 2;
   return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    Counter d(2);
    Counter d1, d2;
    d1 = d.doubler();                            // normal function call
    std::cout << "d1=" << d1.get() << std::endl; // Output : d1=4 
    d2 = d.doubler().doubler();                  // Method chaining
    std::cout << "d2=" << d2.get() << std::endl; // Output : d2=0 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If a function returns a reference to a local object, the object will be destroyed as soon as the function returns (as local objects are). It does *not* persist to the end of the line of the function call.

Accessing an object after it has been destroyed will yield unpredictable results. Sometimes it may work, for some definition of "work", and sometimes it may not. Just don't do it.

Comment: What about R-value reference in c++11?

Comment: @shivakumar: If you want to talk about them, make a new question. That's kind of out of scope for this simple question. ;)

Comment: as you said, for some definition of work, it would work. I say it would always work for simplistic objects and simplistic code as presented in the question. See my answer below.

Comment: @Amit: We'll never know if you're right because we'd have to wait forever to know that it will "always work". I do, however, marvel at your ability to predict the behavior of the C++ compilers of 2042.

Comment: @David, rather than picking on my (admittedly poor) choice of English words, can you, just as an experiment, try this and see if it produces random behavior? No one knows that it would always work. Code that you write today might not work in 2015, let alone 2042. So? Stop writing code, saying that the future behavior of OS/Compiler/Computers is undefined?

Comment: @Amit: It's not undefined. We have standards that define it. That's what the standards are for. But where the standards don't define the language, you may find that all compilers "happen to" act the same because they're all targeting similar hardware. Future hardware may be different.

Comment: @David: most people on this thread understand that the object would be destroyed, and that it is bad, and that it should not be done. But that was not the question ....

Answer (score 0):

```
Counter& doubler()
{ 
Counter tmp;
tmp.i=this->i*2;
return tmp;
}
```

It's undefined behaviour. After return from function - your reference will be dangling, since `Counter` destructor will be called for local object `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is not "why this kind of method chaining is not working?", but instead "why the first ('normal') function call works?"

The answer is there's no way to tell, because it might as well break your program.

To state it clearly: returning temporary object by reference is undefined behavior. Which, of course, means that it might work by coincidence today and stop working tomorrow. All bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns and stack roll back happens it is logical rollback the stack pointer is set with different value. If a function returns a local variable reference then memory location pointing to local may still be with process and has same bits set. However this is not guaranteed and after few more calls will not be valid and may result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Other are all right, in that 'just do not fiddle around with references to local objects'

But as to why it works in one case and not in other

1. When you call it singly, and when the function returns, the object is still lying on the stack. Granted a 'destructed' object - but whatever space the object  used to take is still there on the stack. If you have a simple object, like with a single int member, then there is NOTHING disturbing it on the stack, unless you code allocated something else on the stack, or the destructor decided to do a much thorough job and obliterate an integer member (which most destructors do not do). Granted yada yada, but till the very next line not much is going to happen that would move it from the stack. Your reference is pointing to a valid memory location and your (destructed) object would be there. That is why it works for you.
2. When you call it chained, see the first call returns you a reference to that tmp on the stack. As explained in #1 above, no problem so far. Your (destructed) tmp is still very much there on stack. But notice the moment you call that second doubler. Where is the tmp inside that second doubler function call going to come up? Right where the tmp from your first call was!!! The second call overwrites the object (the tmp with value 4) with a tmp with value 0 (the default constructed one). The second call is in effect made on a Counter which has 0 value, hence you get 0. Extremely tricky - that is why just forget about fiddling with returning references to local variable.

Now Purists may scream - undefined, no no just don't do it - and I am with them - I have myself said twice (now thrice) that do not do it. But people may try it. I bet for a 'simple' object like the following, AND code exactly as in the question (so as to nothing is disturbing the stack), everyone is going to get consistent 4, 0 - no randomness, no undefined ....

```
class Counter
{
public:
    Counter()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    Counter(int k)
    {
        i = k;
    }
    int get()
    {
        return i;
    }
    int i;
    Counter& doubler();
};
```